# How to efficiently split a very long (multiple million characters) string after every nth character in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, split

Let's say I have a string

```rb
string = "hellohellohey"
```

I want to split it every 2nd character so it looks like this

```rb
string = ["he","ll","oh","el","lo","he","y"]
```

I tried using the `scan(/.{2}/)` method but if the array item can't be divided by 2, it doesn't work.

*Edit:* It's necessary to inform you that the 2-character thing was an example. I'm doing something big so I'll be splitting it every 8 **million** characters. So splitting it into individual characters and using `each_slice` doesn't work here. It just freezes my laptop.

Comment: Try using `.{1,2}` to match either 1 or 2 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When processing (very) large strings, it can be useful to wrap them in a [`StringIO`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html). It provides an efficient file-like access to the string.

You can for example read every *n* characters via [`StringIO#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html#method-i-each):

```
string = "hellohellohey"
string_io = StringIO.new(string)

string_io.each(5) do |substring|
  p substring
end
```

Output:

```
"hello"
"hello"
"hey"
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, it tells me that it's an enumerator when I try to count the number of items in the array.

Edit: Nevermind, I used `.to_a`

Comment: @tequila that's expected. With a block, `StringIO#each` yields the characters / substrings. Without a block, it returns an enumerator. I assumed that you wanted to skip the array creation and work on the substrings.

Answer (score 3):

You can chain multiple methods like below:

```
string = 'hellohellohey'
string.chars.each_slice(2).map { |s| s.join }
# => ["he", "ll", "oh", "el", "lo", "he", "y"]
```

[#chars](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-chars) will convert string to character array.

[#each_slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) splits the array into required number of parts.

**Update - Without intermediate/temporary array**

As per the comments, thanks to @Cary Swoveland, temporary array can be avoided as follows.

```
string.each_char.each_slice(2).map { |s| s.join }
```

[#each_char](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-each_char) gives an Enumerator of each character.

Comment: A small point, so small that it is barely discernible: I suggest you use `each_char` rather than `chars` when followed by an `Enumerable` method, to avoid the creation of the temporary array `string.chars`.

Comment: I get your point @CarySwoveland, I started with the same thing but then I couldn't gather 2/required number of characters chars after `each_char`. can you think of chaining it somehow?

Comment: `string.each_char.each_slice(2).map { |s| s.join }`. Note the return value of `string.each_char.each_slice(2) #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: "hellohellohey":each_char>:each_slice(2)>`, a sort of *compound enumerator*.

Comment: Does dividing the string at say 10000 chars at a time help? `string[0..10000]`

Answer (score 3):

The dot matches any character except a newline. You are trying to match 2 times any character and that won't match the last character if the string is odd in length.

You could use a [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) `{1,2}` which is greedy so it first tries to match 2 times.

```
.{1,2}
```

See [a demo](https://ideone.com/o7dTVm)

If you want to match only lowercase characters a-z you might also use `[a-z]` instead of a dot.

Comment: Also works: `/..?/` which is just one more character. The `{}` version you have here is more flexible, though, as you could do `2,5` or `9,300` or whatever you need.

Comment: In addition, you probably want to add the `m` modifier to have `.` match any character (it doesn't match newline by default).